# How to call variable from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, set, call

I want to call username from my table users. But i don't know how to do it can you help me.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `online` = 0 WHERE `username` = $username");
```

but it says **Undefined variable: username**

Comment: please migrate to `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online = 0 WHERE username = '".$username."'");
```

or check `$username` with `isset($username)` perhaps `$username` is null

Comment: it doesn't work I need to page somehow to read the username, to get it from phpmyadmin

Comment: sorry,i do not understand your mean.where is  `$username` the  set?how can get `$username` from phpmyadmin?!which `$username`?

Comment: I want to match the username with the username that is logged in.
But I don't know how

Comment: why??in your site when user login set $username in $_SESSION['username']='admin' and then use this

Answer (score 0):

there is no variable call $username in your code.

Comment: Genious. How did you get that conclusion

Comment: form this "Undefined variable: username"